# Will the questions be migrated over from meta.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, meta, mso-mse-split

Will we get our reputation moved over or questions?

Comment: Looks like they arbitrarily choose 250000 as the post id cutoff. (1st comment on the new Meta.SO!!! AHAHAHAHA)

Comment: Will you even earn reputation? I remember that you won't earn reputation on meta.security.SE

Comment: @Mysticial -1, first post is not actually 23rd

Comment: Oh my! Those _internet dollars_.

Comment: @devnull \*\*useless internet points

Comment: @Mysticial This is the actual first question on MSO (10k only): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250000/select-id-as-post-link-from-posts-where-id-250000

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow will now behave as all other metas in our network: rep is inherited from the parent site.

Questions will be migrated over as necessary.

Comment: Where is your mod diamond?

Comment: @HamZa She only has it on the Meta.

Comment: Rep of `101` after `12` upvotes, is it a bug?

Comment: @devnull No; I have 101 rep on Stack Overflow, which is the parent site for MSO now. Meta rep, except on Meta Stack Exchange, is whatever your rep on the main site is.

Comment: If only the answer devnull was commenting explained exactly that. Oh, wait...

Comment: may this rhyme/ comfort you/ yesterday's master/ nowadays n00b !

Comment: I've noticed that [many Stack Overflow-specific questions are being closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1) instead of being migrated. Will these questions be migrated eventually, even after they have been closed?

Comment: @AndersonGreen No, we've never had any intention of migrating *all* SO-specific questions. Only the ones that are historically relevant or still actionable will be. (So, for example, we won't bother migrating old tag burnination requests from 2012 that never got consensus that the tags were problematic.) [See Shog's comment over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014/228903#comment753455_229487)

Answer (score 28):

I'll begin migrations from MSO to MSE in a short period of time, a process that will likely take a day and a half or so. Rep here just mirrors your rep on Stack Overflow, so nothing is affected *here*.

You *might* lose a tiny bit of rep on MSE as posts get lobbed over, but I'm going to try to minimize this.

**Edit** - I'm probably not going to begin migrations for at least a few hours, there's lots and lots and lots of cached stuff / leagues / etc that we have to deal with, and I'd like a couple of exception-free hours before I start clogging up that particular queue.

Comment: (This may happen later today, I have to wait for things to fully stabilize before I start filling up the migration queue)

Comment: Will a suggested migration path be added for MSO=>MSE and vice versa? (I am imagining throngs of confused users.)

Comment: @Emracool Not immediately, probably at least a month. We don't want to send _too_ much stuff over.

Comment: I think it will be interesting to see what effects this will have on MSO. For example, my meta-rep is now ~225k up from ~1.3k, so I get a ton more privileges here. Of course if a user can handle their responsibilities well on SO, they also should so on MSO, but the sites are  quite different nevertheless. I assume you considered this, but I'm still curious to see what effects this has (if any).

Comment: Have you migrated the favorite question flag with the questions? I've suddenly got no favorites here - which isn't inconceivable but I'd be very surprised, I over-use favorite.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange metas do not have a reputation system. Your reputation is locked to match your parent site's.

Once data.SE gets a MSO snapshot, you will be able to use [one of the many queries there](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/157285/meta-reputation-classifications) to simulate your reputation score.

Answer (score 7):

Some of the SO specific ones will be migrated.

But reputation on meta.SO is tied to SO reputation. You won't get any for posting here.